# Android HTTP clients apache vs HTTPURLConnection

Tags: android, apache, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am having trouble differentiating between the apache HTTP client and HTTPURLConnection.  According to the Android Developer page these are the two HTTP clients included in Android and HTTPURLConnection should be used for Android 2.3 and later.  My problem is that I have an app that calls apache classes and I believe these should be replaced with HTTPURLConnection, but I have no idea how to replace these classes with those proper to my app version.

I have the feeling that I am thinking of this wrong but I would like some advice on what classes I should replace the following with, in order to make my app stable:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what are your target api?

Comment: mininum api in your manifest??

Comment: For Android > 2.2 (Froyo) you should use HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient. Have a look at [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/) or the list of alternatives on that page, because HttpURLConnection is really cumbersome to use.

Comment: would not change implementation until there is specific reason . Like "i need to set socketTimeout val seperate from requestTimeOut val"  
OR "i need to set these custome header vals on the request object ". When u need something that the current implementation does not address , then switch.

Comment: Robert thank you, i do understand that, but i would like to know how to switch as well, could you tell me?